# Phone number is returned as null using Users.ReadBasic.All

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

As per the below points from which I found MS documentation, a user with `User.ReadBasic.All` would be able to fetch the details including 
`mobilePhone` and `businessPhones`, but it doesn't seem to work in my case.

> Note: Getting a user returns a default set of properties only (businessPhones, displayName, givenName, id, jobTitle, mail, mobilePhone, officeLocation, preferredLanguage, surname, userPrincipalName).

Documentation link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

To be more clear, I have two users, user-A with `Directory.Read.All` and `User.ReadBasic.All` permissions, and a user-B with just `User.ReadBasic.All`.
The `businessPhones` and `mobilePhone` fields are non-nulls values while using user-A but are `null` when using user-B.

As per documentation both the users should fetch the values for `businessPhones` and `mobilePhone` which isn't the case.

Comment: It's impossible to tell you why your code isn't working, because you've failed to include your code in the form of a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @KenWhite thanks for responding, this has nothing to do with code, there is a graph explorer in which you can get to see the contacts and the below is the URL, developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer, FYI , it is impossible for someone to answer this, who ever did worked on graph api's.

Answer (score 0):

The `User.ReadBasic.All` scope does not support `mobilePhone` or `businessPhones`. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#remarks-24):

> The *User.ReadBasic.All* permission constrains app access to a limited set of properties known as the basic profile. This is because the full profile might contain sensitive directory information. The basic profile includes only the following properties:
>
> - displayName
> - givenName
> - mail
> - photo
> - surname
> - userPrincipalName

That note isn't referring to the Permission Scopes. It is referring to the default properties that will be returned if you don't provide a specific `$select` query parameter.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time Mark, my bad I missed this, do you by any chance know, which scope will return the mobilePhone and  businessPhones  of the users in the org?I was initially using Directory.Read.All for which Admin Consent is Required and had to change it to User.ReadBasic.All after which the API stopped working as expected.

Comment: You need to use either `Directory.Read.All` or `User.Read.All`. Both however require Admin Consent.